# Compiled ADB from source has big file size

Tags: android, linux, compilation, adb, open-source

I want to recompile adb from source, I downloaded the whole android source (using repo) and from root directory I send "make adb" command to build adb (I use USE_MINGW=1 to build for Windows too). The problem is that the output file (both adb for linux and adb.exe for windows) is about 17MB, which is huge compared to 1,7MB of precompiled adb provided by Google.
I tried using upx at max compression and it went to 5MB, zipped is 4MB. Zipped adb provided by google is 0,7MB still. 
I need to reduce the file size as much as possible since my adb version needs to be downloaded many times. I know that 4MB are not a big deal, but I would like to not use Upx (it is recognized as false positive from some av). Does anyone knows how to reduce the file size of output file during compilation?